# How can I set Timeout for URLConnection.getInputStream()?

Tags: android

I'm using URLConnection.getInputStream() for my app's update check.

This is my code :

```
java.net.URL url = new URL("http://somewhere.com/checkUpdate.html");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeOut(3000);

if(conn!=null){
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())); // app stopped here

    doSomeThing();


}
```

This code is work well in WiFi(normal state), LTE.
but WiFi's state is Unstable, app stopped at conn.getInputStream().

then, I want set timeout for conn.getInputStream().
how can I set timeout?

or, please tell me any solution instead set timeout.
Thanks.

Sorry for short english..

Comment: Have you tried `conn.setReadTimeout(5000)` ?

Comment: Yes, I already try that. But nothing happens.